# Oracle SQL inner join

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following query, which works fine.

```
SELECT  c.id, c.customer_name, b.batch_prefix, b.BatchCount, b.InvoiceCount, e.time_of_delivery, e.time_of_delivery_mail, e.time_of_delivery_clock
FROM koll_customers c
INNER JOIN (
SELECT batch_prefix, COUNT(*) AS BatchCount,
SUM (batch_counter) AS InvoiceCount
FROM koll_batchlogs
WHERE
          exists_db = 0
          and is_checked = 1
         and batch_counter > 0
         and trunc(created_date) > trunc(sysdate-7)
GROUP BY batch_prefix) b
ON b.batch_prefix=c.customer_prefix
INNER JOIN koll_customer_export e
ON c.id = e.id
```

But, when I add another JOIN (last join) with SELECT and WHERE it gives error: "Invalid identifier"

```
SELECT  c.id, c.customer_name, b.batch_prefix, b.BatchCount, b.InvoiceCount
FROM koll_customers c
INNER JOIN (
SELECT batch_prefix, COUNT(*) AS BatchCount,
SUM (batch_counter) AS InvoiceCount
FROM koll_batchlogs
WHERE
          exists_db = 0
          and is_checked = 1
         and batch_counter > 0
         and trunc(created_date) > trunc(sysdate-7)
GROUP BY batch_prefix) b
ON b.batch_prefix=c.customer_prefix
INNER JOIN (
     SELECT time_of_delivery
     FROM koll_customer_export
     WHERE time_of_delivery=2) e
 ON e.id = c.id
```

I wonder, what is problem with the last join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the `join`:

```
INNER JOIN
(SELECT time_of_delivery
 FROM koll_customer_export
 WHERE time_of_delivery=2
) e
ON e.id = c.id
```

You are referring to `e.id`, but you don't have that in the subquery.  Try this:

```
INNER JOIN
(SELECT time_of_delivery, id
--------------------------^
 FROM koll_customer_export
 WHERE time_of_delivery=2
) e
ON e.id = c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 INNER JOIN (
 SELECT time_of_delivery
 FROM koll_customer_export
 WHERE time_of_delivery=2) e
 ON e.id = c.id
```

there is no column named id.